# Comparing an std::string_view and a char

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

The following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main() {
 const char bar{'a'};

 std::string_view sep{"a"sv};
 std::cout << sep.compare(&bar) << std::endl;
 std::cout << sep.compare(std::string_view(&bar)) << std::endl;
 std::cout << (sep == &bar)<< std::endl;
 std::cout << (sep == std::string_view{&bar}) << std::endl;
}
```

produces different results on different compilers:

- -1, -1, 0, 0 on gcc 9.4, 9.5, 12.2
- 0, 0, 1, 1 on clang 11

([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G9nh69WcE))

By massaging the code a bit (adding / removing spaces), I can sometimes get 0&1 on some of the GCC builds. The clang 11 build consistenly prints 0 & 1.

Is the behavior of GCC justified? If so, how do I correctly compare an std::string_view with a char?

Comment: `&bar` is not a zero-terminated string, so the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo D'oh, of course! If you post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: One also needs to verify that the size is the same. Also, you could've easily constructed `std::string_view(&bar,1)` and compare it with `sep`.

Comment: it would be better to change type of `bar`: `constexpr auto bar = "a"sv;`.

Comment: @ALX23z std::string_view::compare takes the (potentially different) size of the views-to-be-compared into account already: https://eel.is/c++draft/string.view#ops-13

Comment: Small tweak in code and compiler settings and even compiler catches error: https://godbolt.org/z/14EGbqfPM

Comment: @MarekR The code I posted was a minimized example of the real code, where the char's are passed to the predicate of std::adjacent_find and the comparison happens inside of the predicate, so I could not make them static. I'll try to remember this for the future, though!

Comment: @Wieland I referred to the molbdnilo's comment where he proposes to compare the `char` versus `sep[0]` ignoring the possible size disparity.

Comment: @Wieland it is a good practice to have `static const` or `static constexpr` in function scope for thing which are known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I correctly compare an std::string_view with a char?

`std::string_view::compare` compares two views. Comparing a `char` from view with `char`:

```
std::cout << (sep.at(0) == bar) << '\n';
```

---

If you want to convert the `char` to a `string_view` and then compare the views (presuming that it is the first character from the view we want to compare with):

```
assert(sep.compare(0, 1, &bar, 1) == 0);
```